# Looking for a candidate function to solve definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm working on a numerical simulation of population dynamics that would be greatly sped up if I could solve the following definite integral:

$$\int_{0}^te^{-[x-\theta(T+\tau)]^2/2\sigma^2}d\tau $$

where $\theta(x)$ is any well behaved sigmoid function such as $\tanh(x)$.   All the parameters are real-valued and $\sigma>0$.  Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Is $T<0$? Otherwise $\theta(T+\tau)$ is approximately constant in the interval from 0 to t.

Comment: For my purposes T needs to be defined over all Reals, however you are correct in noting that $\theta$ is nearly constant unless near to the point of inflection at T=0.